# Active Directory connection Failure

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I need a small help. I am new to active directory. I want to connect my active directory with c#. Here is the sample code i have wrote.

```
public void GetConnection()
{
    var username = "xxxx";
    var domain = "xxxx";
    var password = "xxxx";
    var path = "LDAP://xxxx/CN=xx";

    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(sDomain + "/" + sDefaultOU, sUsername, sServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);        

    ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Users))";       

    var sr = ds.FindAll();

    if (sr != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("success");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
    }
}
```

There is a `COMException was unhandled` near

```
var sr = ds.FindAll();
```

The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll
>
> Additional information: Unspecified error

Can I have some help in fixing the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get a list of users?

Comment: Yes.to get all the a value from all the users such as Telephone number.

Comment: What is the **value** that you construct for the constructor of the `DirectoryEntry`? What do you have in `sDomain` and `sDefaultOU`?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

```
 static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
        {
            // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings  
//This is for ssl secure port for non secure port just make 636 as 389 and //change Authentication as None
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mysystem.domain.com:636","Admin","Domain123",AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);

            return ldapConnection;
        }
```

**

- Step 2

**
In the main function u need to write below function

```
 DirectorySearcher _searcher = null;

        SearchResult result_user = null;
            DirectoryEntry de = createDirectoryEntry();
            object o = de.SchemaEntry;
            _searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + "user1" + "))");
            if (_searcher != null)
            {
                result_user = _searcher.FindOne();
                de.Close();
            }
```